# how to achieve Buy 2 products in some category and get any 1 product in same category for free

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

say for eg in same category

Buy A and B then C product should be free
or 2A then B should be free

Comment: Your achieve this by shopping cart price rule in admin side Marketing -> Cart Price Rule

Comment: @Abdul by default magento don't have this feature plz chk here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/buy-x-product-and-get-y-another-product-free-of-same-category?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it by myself so these are the steps I followed to achieve it

1. I am using magento version 2.1.6. first I've created a new cart price rule find it in below image

[image]

2. Since I am using event "salesrule_validator_process" so in module etc/events.xml I wrote like this

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
>      <event name="salesrule_validator_process">
>         <observer name="custom_cart_rules" instance="Almusbah\SendSms\Observer\CustomCartPriceRules" />
>     </event>
> </config>
> ```

3. Finally Observer file "CustomCartPriceRules.php" does the magic

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Almusbah\SendSms\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

   class CustomCartPriceRules implements ObserverInterface {
       public function __construct() {

       }

       /**
        *
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
        * @return void
        */
       public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

           $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
           $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
           $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();
           $address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
           $qty = $item->getQty();

           if ($rule->getData('name') == 'Buy 2 get 1 free'):

                   // overriding magento rules here and updating Almusbah Offer
                   $result->setAmount(0)
                       ->setBaseAmount(0)
                       ->setOriginalAmount(0)
                       ->setBaseOriginalAmount(0);

                   $item->setDiscountPercent(0);


               $products = [];
               $z = 0;
               $totalQty = 0;
               $dA = 0;
               foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $q):

                   $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($q);

                   if ($validate):
                       $products[$z]['sku'] = $q->getData('sku');
                       $products[$z]['qty'] = $q->getData('qty');
                       $totalQty += $q->getData('qty');
                       $products[$z]['totalQty'] = $totalQty;
                       $freeQty = (int) ($totalQty / 3);
                       $products[$z]['freeQty'] = $freeQty;
                       if ($products[$z]['freeQty'] > 0):
                           $products[$z]['applyDiscount'] = 1;
                           $dicountPercent = 100;
                           $dA = ($products[$z]['freeQty'] * $q->getData('calculation_price'));
                           $products[$z]['discountAmount'] = $dA;
                           $totalQty -= 3*$products[$z]['freeQty']; // appying on each 3 items
                       endif;
                       $z++;
                   endif;
               endforeach;
               //echo '<pre>';print_r($products);
               $chkCurrentSku = $item->getSku();

               foreach ($products as $p):
                   if(isset($p['applyDiscount']) && !empty($p['applyDiscount']) && $chkCurrentSku == $p['sku']):
                       $discountAmount = $p['discountAmount'];
                       $fullDiscount = 100;
                       $item->setDiscountPercent($fullDiscount);
                       $this->almusbahBuy2Get1Offer($discountAmount,$result);
                   endif;
               endforeach;

           endif;


       }

       public function almusbahBuy2Get1Offer($discountAmount, $result) {

                      $result->setAmount($discountAmount)
                           ->setBaseAmount($discountAmount)
                           ->setOriginalAmount($discountAmount)
                           ->setBaseOriginalAmount($discountAmount);
               }

       }
   ```

   ?>
4. That's it don't forget to update the module using

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade